# Save MediaElement file source to isolated storage

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mediaelement, isolatedstorage, progressive-download

With a MediaElement using an external source -- is it possible to play an mp3 while it's downloading, and then when it's finished downloading, save it to isolated storage for future use?

If not, what's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: I think you're right on the first part, there's no way to save from a MediaElement.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get to touch the stream that MediaElement's using. But you could DL, then save to isolated storage, then load that stream into the mediaElement...

Comment: I think the point was to not have to download it first but rather to record it as it's streaming.